# Switching to Different plists by Swiping?

Tags: iphone, ios

This is going to be a bit difficult to explain. I'm usually fine with code on the micro level, but need some guidance on the macro end. Anything would help.

I'm trying to basically create a notecard application, where the user is presented with a screen with a stack of flashcards. There are multiple subjects, each managed by a different .plist. To switch between subject areas, you swipe left and right. I don't know how to most efficiently achieve this using storyboards, which is my primary issue. Could you do this using one view, or do I have to create a different view for every stack of flashcards and create a transition between them?

Thank you very much, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to switch between different views by either swiping left of right, the most logical choice would be to use a UIScrollView with paging enabled. You could then initialize an NSArray and have it store the names of your different PList files and use it to manage your data between views. Obviously this is just one of many solutions to this problems, but when you talk about wanting a swiping action to switch, UIScrollViews would be the iOS default way of doing it.

Here is a tutorial on how to use UIScrollViews with paging:

http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/

Hope that helps!